# Interleaving vector elements with corresponding lists to create new vector of vectors

Tags: list, vector, clojure

I have data in the following format:

```
[["i1" "i2"]
 ['("A" "B" "C" "D") '("red" "blue" "green" "yellow")]]
```

I want to transform this to get a new data structure:

```
[["column" "value"]
 ["i1" "A"]
 ["i1" "B"]
 ["i1" "C"]
 ["i1" "D"]
 ["i2" "red"]
 ["i2" "blue"]
 ["i2" "green"]
 ["i2" "yellow"]]
```

Any help with this difficult problem would be great.

My attempts to far have involved using nested "for" statements, but I cannot get the resulting vectors in the same level as the header vector, despite many attempts to convert the results. I have also used "interleave" and "repeat" on the value for column, but that too creates lists at the wrong level.

Comment: People would appreciate it more & would like to help you more if you tried it Yourself first & also share what you tried

Comment: You have to *quote* the lists thus: `['("A" "B" "C" "D") '("red" "blue" "green" "yellow")]]`

Comment: @shaktimaan Thank you. I added the information.

Comment: @Thumbnail Thank you, a common mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some fun answers here. I will just add that conceptually, I think this is a good place for [`for`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for). For each item in the first vector, you want to pair it with items from the corresponding lists in the second vector.

```
(defn convert [[cols vals]]
    (vec (cons ["column" "value"] ;; turn the list into a vector.
            (for [i (range (count cols)) ;; i <- index over columns
                  j (nth vals i)] ;; j <- items from the ith list
              [(nth cols i) j])))) ;; [col val]

user=>(convert data)
```

This is easily modified to handle more vectors of values:

```
(defn convert [[cols & vals]]
    (cons ["column" "value"]
        (mapcat #(for [i (range (count cols))
                       j (nth % i)]
                   [(nth cols i) j])
                vals)))
```

Comment: Your `for` construct is wrong. In `j` you are iterating through the letters of the individual words. Also, why mess with indices?

Comment: Also, I'm using indices because we don't want to pair every item in `cols` with items from every list in `vals`, and I wanted the `for` to do most of the work. Why? Because I saw four answers, three of them practically identical, and none used `for`. There was nothing wrong with the answers, but we're not here to write code for people, we're here to teach.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I swear that I tried it in my REPL and saw different results this morning -

Comment: @galdre I want to thank you for making use of "for". I tried so long to get it to work, but could not. I think mapcat and cons were my missing pieces, things I didn't consider. This was enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn doit [[is vss]]
  (vec (cons
         ["column" "value"]
         (mapcat (fn [i vs] (mapv (fn [v] [i v]) vs)) is vss))))
```

Comment: Corrected. Previous erroneous version quite properly voted down.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn convert
  [[header data]]
  (->> (mapcat #(map vector (repeat %) %2) header data)
       (cons ["column" "value"])))

(convert '[["i1" "i2"] [("A" "B" "C" "D") ("red" "blue" "green" "yellow")]])
;; => (["column" "value"] 
;;     ["i1" "A"] ["i1" "B"] ["i1" "C"] ["i1" "D"] 
;;     ["i2" "red"] ["i2" "blue"] ["i2" "green"] ["i2" "yellow"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn conform
  [[ks & rows]]
  (mapcat
   (fn [row]
     (mapcat (fn [k val]
               (map (partial vector k) val))
             ks row))
   rows))
```

Your example:

```
(conform [["i1" "i2"] ['("A" "B" "C" "D") '("red" "blue" "green" "yellow")]])
=> (["i1" "A"] ["i1" "B"] ["i1" "C"] ["i1" "D"]
    ["i2" "red"] ["i2" "blue"] ["i2" "green"] ["i2" "yellow"])
```

Bonus:

```
(conform [["i1" "i2"]
          ['("A" "B" "C" "D") '("red" "blue" "green" "yellow")]
          ['("E" "F" "G" "H") '("Mara" "Lara" "Clara" "Foxy")]])

=> (["i1" "A"] ["i1" "B"] ["i1" "C"] ["i1" "D"] 
    ["i2" "red"] ["i2" "blue"] ["i2" "green"] ["i2" "yellow"] 
    ["i1" "E"] ["i1" "F"] ["i1" "G"] ["i1" "H"] 
    ["i2" "Mara"] ["i2" "Lara"] ["i2" "Clara"] ["i2" "Foxy"])
```

More bonus:

```
(conform [["i1" "i2" "i3"]
          ['("A" "B" "C" "D") '("red" "blue" "green" "yellow") ["Ufo"]]
          ['("E" "F" "G" "H") '("Mara" "Lara" "Clara" "Foxy") ["Orange" "Apple"]]])

=> (["i1" "A"] ["i1" "B"] ["i1" "C"] ["i1" "D"] 
    ["i2" "red"] ["i2" "blue"] ["i2" "green"] ["i2" "yellow"] 
    ["i3" "Ufo"] 
    ["i1" "E"] ["i1" "F"] ["i1" "G"] ["i1" "H"] 
    ["i2" "Mara"] ["i2" "Lara"] ["i2" "Clara"] ["i2" "Foxy"] ["i3" "Orange"] ["i3" "Apple"])
```

Creating a map from the result is easy:

```
(reduce (fn [acc [k v]]
          (update-in acc [k] (fnil conj []) v)) {} *1 )

=> {"i3" ["Ufo" "Orange" "Apple"], 
    "i2" ["red" "blue" "green" "yellow" "Mara" "Lara" "Clara" "Foxy"], 
    "i1" ["A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not idiomatic, but did the trick.

```
((fn [coll]
   (let [ks (first coll) vs (last coll)]
     (cons 
      '("column" "value")
      (partition 2 (concat
                    (interleave (repeat (first ks)) (first vs))
                    (interleave (repeat (last ks)) (last vs)))))))
 [["i1" "i2"]
  ['("A" "B" "C" "D") '("red" "blue" "green" "yellow")]])
```